# Slow and unstable wireless connection on RTL8723AE on Ubuntu14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

I've been having some problems with the wi-fi connection on Ubuntu 14.04. I have a Toshiba Satelite with pre-installed Windows 8 which I un-installed. The wi-fi connection on Windows was really good, but since I installed Ubuntu the connection is slow and unstable. I've been using some help from here that I thought it could help, but nothing. Any way I could see the settings that I changed during those attempts? And any way I could solve my problem?

This is the result of `sudo iwlist scan 
wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: E8:39:DF:7B:01:8C
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=38/70  Signal level=-72 dBm

                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"xDD"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000eb6652362
                    Extra: Last beacon: 4ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 0003784444
                    IE: Unknown: 010482848B96
                    IE: Unknown: 03010B
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 32080C1218243048606C`

Comment: How many access points show up on your channel of equivalent or greater signal strength when you do  sudo iwlist scan

Comment: I just posted the result in the question. I didn't really get what you were saying .

Answer (score 0):

You have only one access point listed, which is good, no interference from neighbors, but your signal level is not very good, not terrible, but maybe could be better by ensuring the direct line between your PC and access point is not blocked with large metal objects like filing cabinets or refrigerators. Also try fiddling with the antenna alignment, try a 90 degree rotation of the ap to see if there is any difference in signal strength. Note the strength is listed in negative dBm, so a small negative is better -- look at the quality too, higher is better there.

---

They do sell higher gain antennas for wireless routers too.  Since you don't have any neighbors to interfere with,  that is a good possibility.

Comment: I didn't seem to fix the problem, the connection is still dropping in the interval of 5 to 7 minutes. When it drops i have to disconnect from the router and then connect again.